# Creating a circular border radius on multiple child components

Tags: html, css, reactjs

so what i am trying to do is have a circle which inside of it, contains an image and a description which overlays the image at 50% Opacity. Heres the result so far:

[image]

So, obviously, i want the entire div to have this `border-radius`, and so far have had to set the `parent` and `img` components to have this certain `border-radius`. What i was wondering was how to have all elements with a circular radius,

(bonus points possibly using `border-radius: XX% and not border-radius: XXpx;`). Heres what i have tried so far:

**JSX**

```
return(
  <div className="container">
    <img src={this.props.src} alt=""/>
    <div className="descriptor">
      <h4>{this.props.title}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
  margin: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100px;

  display: inline-block;
  border-radius:100px;
  border:2px solid red;
}

.container img{
   max-width:100%;
   border-radius:100px;
   float: left;
}

.descriptor{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  /*NOTE: Here i have tried using things like border-bottom-left-radius: 750px;
    But yeah that didnt work*/
}
```

Comment: What you need is border-radius 50%, and if there are more than one containers you need to apply this on just make use of classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a demonstration with the comments for the appropriate CSS style attributes.

```css
.roundc{
width:300px;  /*Width and height need to be equal for border radius*/
height:300px; /*50% to work and make the square circular */
display:inline-block;
border-radius: 50%;  /*Make the container circular */
border:3px solid red;
overflow: hidden;   /*Hide the content overflow */
position:relative;  /*To use absolute positioning on img*/
}

.roundc img{ /*To center the large image */
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.roundc span{
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
background:red;
color:white;
width:300px;
height:30px;
text-align:center;
bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="roundc">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350">
  <span> About me </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, i think `overflow: hidden` is what i was missing. Thankyou!

Comment: @RyanTurnbull No problem :)